# Get matching values and key from array in php

Tags: php

How to get only matching values from an array in php.
Example:

```
<?php
$a=array("1"=>"Hello","2"=>"World","3"=>"Check","4"=>"Here");
?>
```

from $a, if i have text like `"He"` or `"ld"` or `"che"` , How to show based on text get matching values and keys an array. Same like sql like query.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you are trying to do? I am not complete sure on what you wan't to do. 
Are you trying to se if "He" exist in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple one liner.

You might be looking for [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php). Using this function you can find possible `REGEX` from your given array.

```
$a=array("1"=>"Hello","2"=>"World","3"=>"Check","4"=>"Here");    
$matches  = preg_grep ("/^(.*)He(.*)$/", $a);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the array and check every value if it contains your search string:

```
        $searchStr = 'He';
        $a=array("1"=>"Hello","2"=>"World","3"=>"Check","4"=>"Here");

        foreach( $a as $currKey => $currValue ){
          if (strpos($currValue, $searchStr) !== false) {
             echo $currKey.' => '. $currValue.' ';
          }
        }
//prints 1 => Hello 4 => Here
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create function for that, like this:

```
function find_in_list($a, $find) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($a as $el) {
        if (strpos($el, $find) !== false) {
            $result[] = $el;
        };
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here is how you could call it:

```
print_r (find_in_list(array("Hello","World","Check","Here"), "el"));
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Hello )
```